# Python group ID and sum value of them to new df

Tags: python, dataframe

```
ProID   Feature1    Feature2    Feature3    Feature4
P100    0           0           1           0
P200    1           0           0           0
P100    0           1           1           0
P100    1           0           0           0
P200    1           1           0           1
P300    1           0           0           1
P400    0           1           1           0
```

I'd like group ProID by sum value in feature column

for example,

```
P100    0   0   1   0
P100    0   1   1   0
P100    1   0   0   0
```

if sum of each feature > 0, put 1
if sum of each feature = 0, put 0

so,
P100 is 1   1   1   0

then new dataframe is

```
ProID   Feature1    Feature2    Feature3    Feature4
P100    1           1           1           0
P200    1           1           0           1
P300    1           0           0           1
P400    0           1           1           0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` with `sum` and `gt` (greater than):

```
df.groupby("ProID").sum().gt(0).astype(int)
```

If the data never gets negative values, you can simplify it using `any`:

```
df.groupby("ProID").any().astype(int)
```

Output:

```
       Feature1  Feature2  Feature3  Feature4
ProID                                        
P100          1         1         1         0
P200          1         1         0         1
P300          1         0         0         1
P400          0         1         1         0
```